# ValueError: in python

Tags: python

**How to solve this Error?**---ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.  Expected: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13], got ['Afghanistan' 'Australia' 'Bangladesh' 'England' 'India' 'Ireland'
'New Zealand' 'Pakistan' 'South Africa' 'Sri Lanka' 'West Indies'
'Zimbabwe' 'no result' 'tied']

**I got above error while using below code**
final = pd.get_dummies(df_teams_2015, prefix=['Team_1', 'Team_2'], columns=['Team_1', 'Team_2'])

## Separate X and y sets

X = final.drop(['Winner'], axis=1)
y = final["Winner"]

## Separate train and test sets

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

rf = XGBRFClassifier(n_estimators=100, subsample=0.9, colsample_bynode=0.2)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

## report performance

print('Mean Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(n_scores), std(n_scores)))

**I used Other other models such as decision trees, Random forests etc. other models working perfectly but in XGboost Im facing this problem**

Comment: Hi @SMa, welcome to the site. It is difficult to figure out the cause of your problem without seeing the source code. Please edit your question and include it, along with any other relevant piece of information, like the solutions you have attempted.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Edited my question with source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code before you fit the model -

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y_train = le.fit_transform(y_train)


rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

*(Also, please consider accepting one (with the tick mark ✓ next to it) if you consider it correct )*